# Search for specific values in data using a lookup table

Tags: sql

I have a lookup table with values I want to check for in the data.

The problem is somewhat like this:

```sql
-- Data with an ID, a group (which is a number) and some letters which belong to that group.
select *
into #data
from (values
    (1, 45, 'A'), 
    (1, 45, 'B'),
    (1, 45, 'C'),
    (2, 45, 'D'))
as data(id, number, letter)

-- The various letters that I expect for each ID in a specific group
select *
into #expected_letters
from (values
    (45, 'A'), 
    (45, 'D'),
    (45, 'E'),
    (123, 'A'),
    (123, 'Q'))
as expected_letters(number, letter)
```

The results that I expect from a query are all letters (from all `id`s from `#data`) that I expect belonging to that group, but are not there. So these results actually:

```
(1, 45, D)
(1, 45, E)
(2, 45, A)
(2, 45, E)
```

In my problem the list is a lot longer with more groups and more id's. I've tried a lot with different joins and set operators, but I can't seem to get my head around this problem.

Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (TSQL, MySQL, Postgre etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my version which is very similar but uses an outer apply instead of multiple joins.  :-

```
select distinct d.id,  aa.number,aa.letter from #data d 
outer apply (select * from #expected_letters el where el.number=d.number and el.letter not in 
(select letter from #data dt where dt.number=d.number and dt.id=d.id)
) aa
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I tried, and it seems to work.  The last inner join aliased "nums" is to remove number 123 from your results, since it doesn't exist for any ID in #data.

```
select e.*, ids.id from #expected_letters e
cross join (select distinct id from #data) ids
full join #data d on e.number = d.number and e.letter = d.letter and d.id = ids.id
inner join (select distinct number from #data) nums on e.number = nums.number
where
    d.id is null
```

--result:

```
number  letter  id
45  A   2
45  D   1
45  E   1
45  E   2
```